# Strange behaviour of html/css

Tags: html, css, position

Well, I have created a jsfiddle snippet as follow

[link to jsfillde](http://jsfiddle.net/eneim/SerVv/1/)

here is the code

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="media">
        <img src="http://i.minus.com/i3qPeX4FjQRFt.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:320px;
    background-color:#efefef;
}

.media {
    wight:100%;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:#a0a0a0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.media > img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

The purpose of this is to show an image on the bottom of #container. But as you can see, the media class has an extra "4px" on its bottom and I have no idea why. It completely destroys the view .. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:bottom` to your image's CSS:

```
.media > img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SerVv/5/)**

Comment: thanks. (so sorry i don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer). i see my code is well displayed. but could you explain the reason for that extra pixels?

Comment: The default vertical-align value is baseline which reserves space for descender text elements like j, y, and g.